# Que veut dire « Bon sang de bois » ?

Tags: sens, argot

J'ai trouvé la phrase « Bon sang de bois » dans mes devoirs. Littéralement, la traduction est « good blood wood », mais je ne comprends pas la signification.

Comment: On ne peut pas traduire ce genre d'expression mot à mot, il faut trouver des équivalences. Je dirais que c'est l'équivalent de l'anglais *blimey* pour *God blind me*. And don't ask me what a minced oath is in French, because I don't know but that's what "bon sang de bois" is (in French).

Comment: C'est un équivalent de "Bon sang de bonsoir".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est une expression familière qui marque l'étonnement ou l'indignation.

Au Moyen-Âge il y avait de nombreux jurons qui comportaient le nom de Dieu. C'est le cas de « Par le sang de Dieu »  et de « Bon sang de Dieu ».
La mention de dieu étant considérée comme blasphématoire par le clergé devenu puissant au 15<sup>e</sup> siècle le nom de dieu a disparu pour donner des expressions qui sont des euphémismes pour éviter de prononcer le nom de dieu, c'est ainsi qu'on a eu *bon sang de bonsoir*, et *bon sang de bois*.

De même « Par le sang de Dieu » est devenu *palsambleu* (qui n'est plus vraiment utilisé de nos jours).

La langue anglaise a un mot (*minced oath*) pour désigner ces jurons dans lesquels on a remplacé la mention de dieu par un euphémisme. Je ne trouve pas d'équivalent en français.

Comment: "Sapristi" from *Tintin* is a minced oath.

Comment: @ChrisW *sapristi* is **in** Tintin but **not from** Tintin (much older!) and indeed it is another one, for *Par le sacre du christ.*

Comment: Je n'avais jamais entendu cette expression en tout cas.

Answer (score 1):

Je me permets de rajouter que dans l'expression "bon sang de bois", le bois fait référence à la statue de Christ, en bois, pour éviter de nommer Dieu.

Comment: Ou de la Croix.