# « Minced oath »: comment rend-on ce filet « mignon » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Dans le contexte d'une [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12856) au sujet d'une *expression familière marquant l'étonnement ou l'indignation*, on se demandait comment rendre l'expression « [*minced oath*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) » en français; la désigne-t-on ou, ne s'agissant que d'une application spécifique de l'[euphémisme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euph%C3%A9misme), se satisfait-on alors d'une description?

---

Le terme *jurer* dans le sens d'*invocation sacrilège des êtres ou choses sacrés* fait l'objet d'une évolution indépendante(1160-1174) du serment, même si le terme *juron*(portant les deux sens à l'origine) est tardif(1599).<sup>1</sup> En ce qui a trait au *minced oath* anglais(voir [aussi](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35156)), son apparition remonterait au 14ième(source: wikipédia, relève que *dieu* et *jésus* seraient le premiers mots à faire l'objet d'un tel traitement). Le sens de 1540 du verbe [*to mince*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mince) dans le contexte de paroles apporte aussi son éclairage: *to clip affectedly in imitation of elegance* - conceptuellement, il s'agit donc à l'origine de restreindre la portée en apparence, de sorte à conférer un air d'élégance. Mais le sens *dans l'intérêt du décorum* apparaît à la fin du 16ième. Même s'il ne semble plus y avoir de connotation de superficialité(?), la fonction du *minced oath* fait toujours l'objet de réflexions.

D'autre part, il ne manque pas de mots pour décrire un juron ainsi « détaillé »... et, vu [*mincer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mincer), la métaphore culinaire semble tout à fait indiquée ici, selon qu'elle  s'attarde à la finesse de cette matière([*affiné*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affin%C3%A9), [*raffiné*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raffin%C3%A9)), à sa minceur ([*émincé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9minc%C3%A9), [*aminci*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aminci), [émacié](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/emaci%C3%A9)), à sa teneur([*dégraissé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9graiss%C3%A9)), à sa pureté ([*épuré*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pur%C3%A9), [*filtré*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/filtr%C3%A9), [*décanté*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cant%C3%A9)), à son [innocuité(morale)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/innocuit%C3%A9)([*inoffensif*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inoffensif)... éventuellement convenable), à la douceur de son goût([*adouci*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adouci), [*édulcoré*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9dulcor%C3%A9)), à sa force(avec connotations; [*affaibli*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affaibli), [*amoindri*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amoindri), [*dilué*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dilu%C3%A9)) et encore bien d'autres assurément, dépendamment de l'opinion qu'a une personne de cette forme d'euphémisme, et ainsi du ton qu'elle veut bien donner à son propos à ce sujet. Mais y a-t-il un terme à préférer, qu'elle *ne* [*mâche*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A2cher) ou *pas ses mots* ?

---

<sub>1. Voir *jurer/juron* dans *Dictionnaire historique de la langue francaise*, Alain Rey, ed. Le Robert.</sub>

Comment: For the purpose of looking for a French alternative to "minced oath," can we consider vulgarities/"gros mots" that don't relate to sacred things/beings as "oaths", or must/should the translation that you seek relate to "invocation sacrilège"?

Comment: Apparemment le mot québécois est sacre ( http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Sacres_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois ), et le plus connu est je pense 'sacre de dieu' -> 'sacrebleu'. Je ne connais pas le mot générique en France pour cette atténuation non plus.

Comment: [They're also calling it](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C3%A2line_de_bine) an *adoucissement*.

Comment: @ChrisW Which leads directly to "Juron adouci" I think you got it. (sorry don't know how to embed sites in comments) https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A0LEV70m8rpU8XMAHxwlnIlQ;_ylc=X1MDMTM1MTE5NTY4NQRfcgMyBGZyA3locy1tb3ppbGxhLTAwMQRncHJpZANxZXNUTm00MFJKNkhCc1FndEtPbUdBBG5fcnNsdAMwBG5fc3VnZwM0BG9yaWdpbgNzZWFyY2gueWFob28uY29tBHBvcwMwBHBxc3RyAwRwcXN0cmwDBHFzdHJsAzE0BHF1ZXJ5AyJqdXJvbiBhZG91Y2kiBHRfc3RtcAMxNDIxNTM3ODU1?p=%22juron+adouci%22&fr2=sb-top-search&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-001 and http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2459669

Comment: @user5628 is right. We could prefix with `sacré` before an insult or just a pejorativ word like "sacré pirate"

Comment: j'aime bien "juron édulcoré" c'est tout à fait ça. On pourrait dire aussi "expurgé" comme quand certaine images d'un reportage sont coupées/censurées.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might call it a [délicatesse](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9licatesse) ... because its *scrupules sur ce qui touche à la probité* fits with 'minced' oath, and, *délicatesse* has a *soupçon* of the "culinary delicacy" (*agréable au goût*) also.

Alternatively maybe a *juronet* or *juronette*, or (following Papa Poule's line of thinking) "un fils de juron".

---

The above are jokes of mine, i.e. neologisms.

In existing usage you can find [un adoucissement](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C3%A2line_de_bine) being used:

> De *câline*, lui même **un adoucissement** de *calice*

Or *Juron adouci* (see [here](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Juron+adouci%22) and [here](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Juron+adouci%22&tbm=bks)) is used -- not used very often, but the phrase is descriptive enough that you could understand what it means even without having seen it before.

Comment: Un adoucissement/juron adouci is going to be hard to improve upon, imo.

Comment: @PapaPoule I hope it's understood that you deserve the credit for 'juron adouci'. How did you discover it: did you invent it yourself and then search for it to see whether it already existed?

Comment: Oh no, I would never have even thought of it without seeing your comment with adoucissement (I hadn't even noticed that it was actually mentioned in the question itself until @Amphiteóth pointed that out in a comment up top). "Juron abrégé" and "juron dilué" (unmentioned until now) were the only things that I had been able to think of (other than my questionable "espèce de" idea) until seeing your inspirational comment. "Juron adouci" was/is yours and I hope that it eventually contributes to your good answer's acceptance!

Answer (score 2):

When someone calls me a ["mot insultant"/"gros mot" (disons "con", par exemple)] in French, they sometimes preface the word with "espèce de."  Usually with only the context/tone of voice/gravity of my transgression I can surmise that being an "espèce de con" is somehow worse than being simply a "con."

In light of the above discussion of my personal experiences with the "reinforcing nature" of "espèce de" when followed by an insulting word addressed to a person, the suggestions proposed below might seem to be just the opposite of what you seek.  However, other meanings/uses of "espèce" and "espèce de" include "comparable/semblable" and "sorte/manière", without emphasizing/reinforcing the negative.

Therefore, I think that prefacing "juron(s)" (for minced blasphemous oaths) and "gros mot(s)"/"grossièreté(s)" (for minced, non-blasphemous oaths/vulgarities) would accurately capture the notion in French, with a gentle double entendre thrown in for good measure:

"Espèce de juron" = "minced (blasphemous) oath", e.g., "Sang de bois" pour "sang de dieu"

"Espèce de gros mot"/"Espèce de grossièreté" = "minced (non-blasphemous) oath/vulgarity",e.g., "mince" pour "merde"

I really tried to work with the French word "mince" to get something, because:

1) as you mention the cooking/chopping sense of "mince" in French is spot-on with its "word" sense in English;

2) "mince" itself, as mentioned above, is a minced (non-blasphemous) oath/vulgarity in French for "merde"; and

3) 'mince" is close to an antonym for "gros" in French,

all of which leading me to the following:

"gros mot(s) mince(s)"/"gros mot(s) mincé(s)" and even just "mot(s) mince(s)"/"mot(s) mincé(s)."

However, all of these seemed to me to be a bit too "mignon"-sy (except perhaps the last one, "mot(s) mincé(s)"), so I went with "espèce de ...."

Comment: Pas pour changer ma reponse, mais voila une reference a la notion d'un "juron 
abrégé" (Paragraph 53) ( "http://www.archive.org/stream/bulletinduglossa00zuriuoft/bulletinduglossa00zuriuoft_djvu.txt ) et puis une autre ( http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=64010 )